# Union of the arbitrary number of object types in an array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I've been attempting to create a type which can infer the type of an array based on the unknown number of object types which are in the array. I want the resulting type to be an array of the union of all the types that are in the array.

Some things I've looked into from the [advance types documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

- Union Types
- Conditional Types

Example:

```
interface A {a: number;}
interface B {b: string;}
interface C {c: boolean;}
const a = {a:0}, b = {b:"str"}, c = {c:true};

type UnionOfArrayTypes = /*?*/;

let arr: UnionOfArrayTypes;
arr = [a,b] // A|B[]
arr = [a,c] // A|C[]
arr = [a,b,c] // A|B|C[]
```

I want to avoid simply defining many possible definitions, and I want to avoid calling it 'any' - I want typescript to be able to infer the type from the array itself.

Edit:

To give a better example of why/how to requirement came up -
I'm defining an extend/merge function which combined multiple objects properties together.

```
function _merge<T extends object, U extends object>(destination: T, source: U): T & U {
  return {...destination, ...source};
}

export function merge<T extends object, U extends object>(destination: T, ...sources: U[]): T & U {
  return _merge(destination, sources.length == 0 ? undefined : sources.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      return _merge(acc, curr);
  }, sources[0]));
}
```

I want to change the merge function to take any number of objects and merge them together and provide the correct union type for the return type.

Currently (in the example above) the compiler only allows the merge function to accept an array of a single type, but I want to be able to pass it any number of different objects together and get the correct return type.

So then I could use it like so:

```
// using the defined variables from above
const result = merge(a,b,c) // type is the union type A|B|C
```

Comment: What's wrong with `type UnionOfArrayTypes = (A | B | C)[]`?

Comment: Hi @kaya3, I added more details above to give a better example of the use case which hopefully should answer your question.